# How to take the average of a stochastic differential equation?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I am solving a set of stochastic differential equations and I need some feedback about if what I am doing is correct.

Given a vector $\boldsymbol{C}(t)=(C_+(t),C_-(t))^T$, we can writte a set of differential equations as $\frac{d}{dt}\boldsymbol{C}(t)=\boldsymbol{A}(t)\boldsymbol{C}(t)$, where $\boldsymbol{A}(t)$ is a 2x2 matrix with stochastic variables. Specifically,

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{A}(t)=
\begin{pmatrix}
  -\gamma/2 -i \alpha(t)\alpha^*(t) & \alpha^*(t)\dot{\alpha}(t) \\
  \alpha(t)\dot{\alpha}^*(t) & -\gamma/2 +i \alpha(t)\alpha^*(t)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

where $\gamma>0$ and $\alpha(t)$ is a Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process described by $\frac{d}{dt} \alpha(t)=-(\kappa/2) \alpha(t)+\sqrt{\kappa n_{th}} \eta(t)$, such that $\overline{\eta(t)}=0$ and $\overline{\eta(t)\eta(t')}=\delta(t-t')$. Therefore, one can find that $\overline{\alpha^*(t)\alpha(t)}=n_{th}$.

I am interested in the average of $\overline{|C_{\pm}(t)|^2}=\overline{C_{\pm}(t)C^*_{\pm}(t)}$, or if it can not be done exactly, at least some flavour of it.

I would like to know if my attempted solution is correct or not, such because I am doing some risky assumptions. First, we formally integrate the set of equations

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{C}(t)=e^{\int_0^t {\rm d}\tau\boldsymbol{A}(\tau)}\boldsymbol{C}(0)
\end{equation}

Then, the quantity I am interested in can be found by the matrix elements of

\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{C}(t)\boldsymbol{C}^\dagger(t)=e^{\int_0^t {\rm d}\tau\boldsymbol{A}(\tau)}\boldsymbol{C}(0)\boldsymbol{C}^\dagger(0) e^{\int_0^t {\rm d}\tau\boldsymbol{A}^\dagger(\tau)}
\end{equation}

While the matrix in the middle is just some coefficient, it is surrounded by stochastic integrals. So I just take the average. And this is where I make my first approximation which I think it's wrong, but I do not know better. I assume that

\begin{equation}
\overline{e^{\int_0^t {\rm d}\tau\boldsymbol{A}(\tau)}\boldsymbol{C}(0)\boldsymbol{C}^\dagger(0) e^{\int_0^t {\rm d}\tau\boldsymbol{A}^\dagger(\tau)}}\simeq \overline{e^{\int_0^t {\rm d}\tau\boldsymbol{A}(\tau)}}\boldsymbol{C}(0)\boldsymbol{C}^\dagger(0)\overline{e^{\int_0^t {\rm d}\tau\boldsymbol{A}^\dagger(\tau)}}
\end{equation}

Finally, I again do the following approximation

\begin{equation}
\overline{e^{\int_0^t {\rm d}\tau\boldsymbol{A}(\tau)}}\simeq e^{\int_0^t {\rm d}\tau\overline{\boldsymbol{A}(\tau)}}
\end{equation}

And this is something I can evaluate:
\begin{equation}
\overline{\boldsymbol{A}(t)}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  -\gamma/2 -i n_{th} & -\kappa/2 n_{th} \\
   -\kappa/2 n_{th} & -\gamma/2 +i n_{th}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

where I have used $\overline{\alpha^*(t)\eta(t)}=0$ because in an Itô stochastic equation, the variable and the noise are uncorrelated.

After this, I can solve the equations for $|C_{\pm}(t)|^2$. It is, however, highly unlike that this is the correct result, as there are plenty of (unjustified) approximations.

I would appreciate it if somebody would tell me if my approximations are justified, and if not, what would be the correct approach?

PD: In case somebody wonders where that set of stochastic differential equations, they appear when one tries to solve the adiabatic theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_theorem) where one considers the time-dependent Hamiltonian to be stochastic time-dependent.

Comment: Firstly, it is to be noted that $\exp\left(\int_0^t A(\tau) \,\mathrm{d}\tau\right)C(0)$ is not the solution of $\dot{C}(t) = A(t)C(t)$ in most cases when $A$ is not a constant matrix.

Comment: Secondly, the first approximation is a dangerous assumption without justification, because it is equivalent to $\langle ABC \rangle \approx \langle A \rangle \langle B \rangle \langle C \rangle$, i.e. $A,B,C$ are (almost) uncorrelated.

Comment: Thirdly, the second approximation, namely $\langle e^X \rangle \approx e^{\langle X \rangle}$, is rarely efficient. For instance, we have $\langle e^X \rangle = e^{\langle X^2\rangle /2} = e^{\sigma^2/2} \not\approx e^\mu = e^{\langle X \rangle}$ in the case of a gaussian variable $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$.